# Rails 5 - Current ExecJS runtime does't support ES6. Please install latest Node.js

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby, assets

In rails 5, I have created a new app with the below gems

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
gem "less-rails" #Sprockets (what Rails 3.1 uses for its asset pipeline) supports LESS
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.1'
gem 'bootstrap-glyphicons'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "letter_opener_web"
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'local_time'
```

In application.html.erb file,

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': true %>
```

In application.js,

```
 //= require rails-ujs
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require activestorage
 //= require popper.min
 //= require local-time
 //= require bootstrap
 //= require_tree .
```

When I start the server and opens a localhost:3000, I am getting an error like `Current ExecJS runtime does't support ES6. Please install latest Node.js.`

Also I have tried to fix it by `sudo apt-get install nodejs` but same error is displaying. And the `node -v` is `v8.11.2`

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: have you tried to remove the `require` in `application.js` one by one to figure out which one triggers the issue? Also have you tried to upgrade to `node 10.x`?

Comment: I have upgraded the `node` to `v10.7.0` version and I checked by removing all `require` but same error

Comment: then throw out `gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby`

Comment: after nodejs installation, uninstall the gems and reinstall it again. mainly rubyracer or execjs.

Comment: I have tried as you said but same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `execjs` is trying to use nodejs installed as apt package which is old. You can either create link nodejs -> node as execjs firstly looking for nodejs and then for node:

```
ln -s $(which node) $(which node)js
```

or just remove nodejs installed from apt package:

```
apt-get remove nodejs
```

and `execjs` will use node

Answer (score 0):

Remove `gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby` and do `bundle install` again since you have node.js(latest) installed. This should fix the issue mostly.